# Returning large string errors

Tags: java

Alright. This is giving me two errors when compiled. Errors are between ()
First: "; expected" at -(,) price=-

Second: "not a statement" at -basketPrice (+) "]";-

Can anyone see why this is?

```
public String toString(){
   String mleh = "FruitBasket[f1=Fruit[ name=" + fruit1.getName()+ ", price=" + fruit1.getPrice()+"], f2=Fruit[ name=" +fruit2.getName()+", price="+ fruit2.getPrice();
   mleh = mleh + "],f3=Fruit[ name=" fruit3.getName() + ", price=" + fruit3.getPrice() + "], message=" + message + ", price=" + basketPrice + "]";
   return mleh;
}
```

Comment: Use an IDE to figure it out.

Comment: At the very least, you are missing a `+` between `"],f3=Fruit[ name="` and `fruit3.getName()`.

Comment: Thank you my good sir. You actually solved it. I had three friends look at this and we ALL missed that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Missed a +

`mleh = mleh + "],f3=Fruit[ name="` **+** `fruit3.getName()`

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder for building up large complicated strings.  That way if you typo something, the compiler can give you a line number that points to a specific problem area, rather than "line 1 doesn't work".

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("FruitBasket[f1=Fruit[ name=");
    sb.append(fruit1.getName());
    sb.append(", price=");
    sb.append(fruit1.getPrice());
    sb.append("], f2=Fruit[ name=");
    sb.append(fruit2.getName());
    sb.append(", price=");
    sb.append(fruit2.getPrice());
    sb.append("],f3=Fruit[ name=");
    sb.append(fruit3.getName());
    sb.append(", price=");
    sb.append(fruit3.getPrice());
    sb.append("], message=");
    sb.append(message);
    sb.append(", price=");
    sb.append(basketPrice);
    sb.append("]");
    String mleh = sb.toString();
```